# Combined LIKE and CONTAINS Query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-like

I have the followed query which contains as well a LIKE as an Contains-Condition in the WHERE clause.

```
   SELECT *   FROM [dbo].[SearchableContents]  
   WHERE

   (Title LIKE '%thisreturnsnothing%')  --no results match this condition

  OR 

 (contains([Content], '"existingcontent*"')) --this condition is matched by some results
```

As mentioned in the code example above, the LIKE-Part does not match any entries in the database whereas the contains-condition does.

Now here is some interesting behaviour:
Although "OR" is meant to return the results matched by the contains-lookup, nothing is returned by the query.

If the LIKE-Part is replaced by something similar (in the aspect of logic) like 1 = 0, the query behaves as expected.

```
   SELECT *   FROM [dbo].[SearchableContents]  
   WHERE

   1 = 0 -- returns false, duh

  OR 

 (contains([Content], '"existingcontent*"')) --this condition is matched by some results
```

So my question: What is the point with this curious correlation with Like, Contains and OR?

EDIT:
After verifying the issue in this question was real with estimated 150 examples, we now cant reproduce it anymore.

To answer the question from @sagi we added the title column to our full text catalog which somehow solved the whole problem.

Thank you for your time and sorry for leaving this whole case this unsatisfying.

Comment: Can you show [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it?

Comment: What happens if you use `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` on both of them?

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @sagi: Exclusive usage of `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` seems to behave correctly.
@IvanStarostin `@@VERSION` returns Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)